# Select 2 tables with one select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables on my database. One table has categories and the other one has posts. In the category table I have a column called "active".

What I'm trying to do, is to select all posts which have category=0.

Here's the select that I got so far:

```
SELECT tb_posts.*, tb_categories.active 
FROM tb_posts, tb_categories 
WHERE tb_categories.active='0' 
ORDER BY datapub DESC
```

The above query doesn't work as it loads all posts not matter the category status. :(

Comment: You have to join the two tables, see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `left join`:

```
SELECT tp.*, tc.active 
FROM tb_posts tp
LEFT JOIN tb_categories tc ON tb.category_id = tc.id
WHERE tc.active='0' 
ORDER BY datapub DESC
```

The join is done on the `category` column (replace with proper column name - this was my guess) which is (probably) referencing the `id` in the `tb_categories` (again, replace the name).

For an exact query, please show your table structures.

Comment: It says "tb_posts" unknown. Which is weird because I double checked the names. :S

Comment: My bad, forgot to use the same aliases in the select (updated query). Can you give it another spin?